# Incorrect datetime value error for valid timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am getting error `#1292 Incorrect datetime value` when trying to insert '2022-03-13 02:21:55' as a timestamp. If I change the hour from 2 to 1 or 3, it works. It won't when it's 2 though, and I can't figure out why. The table structure is as follows

`` CREATE TABLE `test_table` ( `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ``

Comment: Use `date` and not `timestamp`. But it should work in both cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa974e/1

Comment: daylight savings?